# Anonymous meeting join - Skype UCWA for online

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa

I am trying to join a meeting anonymously through a meeting URI and this does not seem to work. I went to the SKYPE UCWA site and went to the interactive SDK - and tried to join a meeting anonymously from there but the page does not do anything.

https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk

Below is the code that I am trying to join a meeting anonymously, but the call to client.signInManager.signIn never completes and neither any exception is thrown.

Looking for suggestions to resolve this issue. Also, if someone has working code of joining a meeting anonymously using SKYPE web sdk (UCWA), please share the same. Thanks.

```js
function InitialiseSkype() {
                Skype.initialize({ apiKey: config.apiKey }, function (api) {
                window.skypeWebAppCtor = api.application;
                window.skypeWebApp = new api.application();
                client = new window.skypeWebAppCtor;
                //once intialised, sign in
                           
                alert("Skype SDK Initialized");
                JoinAnonymous();
                
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                alert('Cannot load the SDK.');
            });
        } 

function JoinAnonymous(){
client.signInManager.signIn({
                version: config.Version,
                name: $('#name').val(),
                meeting: $('#meetingUri').val()
            }).then(function () {
                alert('Signed In, Anonymously');
                var conversation = application.conversationsManager.getConversationByUri(uri);
            }, function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did sign in anonymously using that code :

```js
//Init
    var config = {apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255', // SDK
                 apiKeyCC: '9c967f6b-a846-4df2-b43d-5167e47d81e1' // SDK+UI
                 };

     Skype.initialize({ apiKey: config.apiKey }, function (api) {
         window.skypeWebApp =  new api.application; 
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("cannot load the sdk package", err);
      }); 

//Actual code
    var uri ="sip:xxxxxxxx;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:xxxxxxxx";
    window.skypeWebApp.signInManager.signIn({
      name: "pseudo",
      meeting:uri
    }).then(function () {
      alert('Signed In, Anonymously');

    }, function (error) {
      alert(error);
    });
```

I did connect with the uri given in the ucwa.skype interactive web sdk page.
But I did not manage to join the conversation after that, probably because the interactive sample does not really create the room.

I can join a meeting from a office365 account while logged in with a sample account. However I can not join anonymously my meeting room. 
Do you try with an on-premise account or with a office365 account ?

Comment: Thanks Lemni for replying..the issue was with Skype for Business online. What I understand now is anonymous meeting join is not yet supported for SFB online.

Comment: I think the support of SFB online is not well defined yet. You can actually sign in with online accounts using ucwa but not directly with the Skype web sdk tools...So it seems logical that anonymous meeting is not yet supported..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Anonymous join for a meeting is not yet available for Skype For Business online.

Answer (score 0):

New update of WebSDK now support anonymous meeting join for SfB Online

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    // this will be populated when the auth token is fetched
    // it is later needed to sign into Skype for Business
    var authDetails = {};

    // A reference to the Skype SDK application object
    // set during initialization
    var app;

    displayStep(0);
    registerUIListeners();

    // Initializing the Skype application
    Skype.initialize({
        apiKey: '9c967f6b-a846-4df2-b43d-5167e47d81e1'
    }, function (api) {
        console.log('Skype SDK initialization successful');

        app = api.UIApplicationInstance;

        // Once it is initialized, display a UI prompt for a meeting URL
        displayStep(1);
    }, function (err) {
        console.error('Skype SDK initialization error:', err);
    });

    // After the user submits the meeting URL the next step is to 
    // fetch an auth token
    function getToken(evt) {
        var input = evt.target.querySelector('input'),
            meetingUrl = input.value,
            request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            data;

        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log('Fetching auth token from meeting url:', meetingUrl);

        function guid() {
            function s4() {
                return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                .toString(16)
                .substring(1);
            }
            return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
                s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
        }

        var sessionId = guid();
        data = 'ApplicationSessionId=' + sessionId +
            '&AllowedOrigins=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href) +
            '&MeetingUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(meetingUrl);

        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (request.status === 200) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(request.response);

                    authDetails.discoverUrl = response.DiscoverUri;
                    authDetails.authToken = "Bearer " + response.Token;

                    console.log('Successfully fetched the anonymous auth token and discoverUrl', authDetails);
                    displayStep(2);
                }
                else {
                    console.error('An error occured, fetching the anonymous auth token', request.responseText);
                }
            }
        };

        request.open('post', 'http://webrtctest.cloudapp.net/getAnonTokenJob');
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
        request.send(data);
    }

    // This uses the auth token and discovery URL to sign into Skype
    // and join the meeting
    function joinAVMeeting(evt) {
        var input = evt.target.querySelector('input'),
            name = input.value;

        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log('Joinig meeting as:', name);

        app.signInManager.signIn({
            name: name,
            cors: true,
            root: { user: authDetails.discoverUrl },
            auth: function (req, send) {
                // Send token with all requests except for the GET /discover
                if (req.url != authDetails.discoverUrl)
                    req.headers['Authorization'] = authDetails.authToken;
                return send(req);
            }
        }).then(function () {
            // When joining a conference anonymously, the SDK automatically creates
            // a conversation object to represent the conference being joined
            var conversation = app.conversationsManager.conversations(0);

            console.log('Successfully signed in with anonymous online meeting token');

            registerAppListeners(conversation);

            // This turns on local video and joins the meeting
            startVideoService(conversation);

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error('Unable to join conference anonymously:', error);
        });


        function registerAppListeners(conversation) {
            conversation.selfParticipant.video.state.when('Connected', function () {

                console.log('Showing self video');

                document.querySelector('.self').style.display = 'inline-block';
                setupContainer(conversation.selfParticipant.video.channels(0), document.querySelector('.self .video'));
                displayName(document.querySelector('.self'), conversation.selfParticipant);

                console.log('The video mode of the application is:', conversation.videoService.videoMode());

                if (conversation.videoService.videoMode() === 'MultiView') {
                    // Loading the sample in any other browser than Google Chrome means that 
                    // the videoMode is set to 'MultiView'
                    // Please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/ptvideogroup
                    // on an example on how to implement group video.
                }

                // When in active speaker mode only one remote channel is available.
                // To display videos of multiple remote parties the video in this one channel
                // is switched out automatically, depending on who is currently speaking
                if (conversation.videoService.videoMode() === 'ActiveSpeaker') {
                    var activeSpeaker = conversation.videoService.activeSpeaker;

                    setupContainer(activeSpeaker.channel, document.querySelector('.remote .video'));

                    activeSpeaker.channel.isVideoOn.when(true, function () {
                        document.querySelector('.remote').style.display = 'inline-block';
                        activeSpeaker.channel.isStarted(true);

                        console.log('ActiveSpeaker video is available and has been turned on.');
                    });

                    activeSpeaker.channel.isVideoOn.when(false, function () {
                        document.querySelector('.remote').style.display = 'none';
                        activeSpeaker.channel.isStarted(false);

                        console.log('ActiveSpeaker video is not available anymore and has been turned off.');
                    });

                    // the .participant object changes when the active speaker changes
                    activeSpeaker.participant.changed(function (newValue, reason, oldValue) {
                        console.log('The ActiveSpeaker has changed. Old ActiveSpeaker:', oldValue && oldValue.displayName(), 'New ActiveSpeaker:', newValue && newValue.displayName());

                        if (newValue) {
                            displayName(document.querySelector('.remote'), newValue);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            conversation.state.changed(function (newValue, reason, oldValue) {
                if (newValue === 'Disconnected' && (oldValue === 'Connected' || oldValue === 'Connecting')) {
                    console.log('The conversation has ended.');
                    reset();
                }
            });
        }

        function setupContainer(videoChannel, videoDiv) {
            videoChannel.stream.source.sink.format('Stretch');
            videoChannel.stream.source.sink.container(videoDiv);
        }

        function displayName(container, person) {
            container.querySelector('.displayName .detail').innerHTML = person.displayName();
        }

        function startVideoService(conversation) {
            conversation.videoService.start().then(null, function (error) {
                console.error('An error occured joining the conversation:', error);
            });
            displayStep(3);
        }
    }

    function endConversation(evt) {
        var conversation = app.conversationsManager.conversations(0);

        evt.preventDefault();

        conversation.leave().then(function () {
            console.log('The conversation has ended.');
            reset();
        }, function (error) {
            console.error('An error occured ending the conversation:', error);
        }).then(function () {
            reset();
        });
    }


    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //UI helper functions
    function displayStep(step) {
        var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.step');

        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
            var node = nodes[i];

            node.style.display = 'none';

            if (i === step) {
                node.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    }

    function registerUIListeners() {
        document.querySelector('.step1').onsubmit = getToken;
        document.querySelector('.step2').onsubmit = joinAVMeeting;
        document.querySelector('.step3').onsubmit = endConversation;
    }

    function reset() {
        window.location = window.location.href;
    }

})();
```

https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-docs/blob/master/Skype/WebSDK/samples/Meetings/Anonymous%20Online/standalone/index.js